# howto dynamically add gorm Scopes by query parameters

Tags: go, go-gorm

My challenge: according to given url parameters i need to dynamically add specific scopes. What would be the best way to implement it?

```golang
package handler

import(
  "net/http"
  "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func scopeA(age int) func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
  return func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return db.Where("age > ?", age)
  }
}

func scopeB(cc string) func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
  return func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return db.Where("country_code = ?", cc)
  }
}

func scopeDefault(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
  return db.Where("active = ?", true)
}

func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  values := r.URL.Query()

  user := []model.User{}

  // howto add additional scope only if specific url parameter is given?

  var age int
  var cc string

  if values.Has("country_code") {
    cc = values.Get("country_code")
  }

  if values.Has("age") {
    age = values.Get("age")
  }

  if err := db.Scopes(
    scopeDefault,
    // scopeA(age) only if parameter given,
    // scopeB(cc) only if parameter given,
  ).Find(&user).Error; err != nil {
    respondError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
    return
  }

  respondJSON(w, http.StatusOK, user)
}
```

i tried to have a look at the implementation of gorm Scopes:

```golang
// impelementation of gorm Scopes member-function
// https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/v1.22.5/chainable_api.go#L260
func (db *DB) Scopes(funcs ...func(*DB) *DB) (tx *DB) {
  tx = db.getInstance()
  tx.Statement.scopes = append(tx.Statement.scopes, funcs...)
  return tx
}
```

but because tx.Statement.scopes is not exported, it seems not possible to e.g.simply append my `scopeA` or `scopeB`

```golang
// won't work
tx.Statement.scopes = append(tx.Statement.scopes, scopeA(age))
```

Could anyone push me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/gorilla/schema"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type ParamObj struct {
    Age         *int    `json:"age" schema:"age" qrstr:"age > ?"`
    CountryCode *string `json:"country_code" schema:"country_code" qrstr:"country_code = ?"`
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var db *gorm.DB // example open connection

        paramObj := new(ParamObj)
        err := schema.NewDecoder().Decode(paramObj, r.URL.Query())
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("ParamObj: %+v\n", paramObj)

        var temp interface{}
        db.Scopes(customStructFilter(paramObj)...).Find(&temp)

        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func customStructFilter(v interface{}) []func(*gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    var arr = make([]func(*gorm.DB) *gorm.DB, 0)
    vl := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem()
    typ := reflect.TypeOf(v).Elem()
    for idx := 0; idx < vl.NumField(); idx++ {
        if !vl.Field(idx).IsNil() {
            arr = append(arr, func(d *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
                return d.Where(typ.Field(idx).Tag.Get("qrstr"), vl.Field(idx).Interface())
            })
        }
    }
    return arr
}
```

Accepting Query parameter by decode it into Object by using `gorilla/schema` (need `schema` tag), and adding `qrstr` tag for `customFilter`.

Well, if you add a validation check inside your scopeA() and scopeB(), it is more than enough. Something like this

```
// scopeA(r.URL.Query().Get("age"))
func scopeA(age string) func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
        if age == "" {
            return db
        }
        if ageInt, err := strconv.Atoi(age); err == nil {
            return db.Where("age > ?", ageInt)
        } else {
            return db
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an easy and clear solution. As long as the number of possible query-params are'nt that many this seems to me the most adequate.
Allthough i liked Davids elaborated solution very much. Thank you!

```golang
package handler

import(
  "net/http"
  "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func scopeA(age int) func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
  return func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return db.Where("age > ?", age)
  }
}

func scopeB(cc string) func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
  return func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return db.Where("country_code = ?", cc)
  }
}

func scopeDefault(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
  return db.Where("active = ?", true)
}

func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  values := r.URL.Query()

  user := []model.User{}

  tx := db.Scopes(scopeDefault)
  tx, err = buildScopesFromQueryParams(tx, values)

  if err != nil {
    respondError(w, http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
  }

  if err := tx.Find(&user).Error; err != nil {
    respondError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error())
    return
  }

  respondJSON(w, http.StatusOK, user)
}


func buildScopesFromQueryParams(tx *gorm.DB, values url.Values) (*gorm.DB, error) {
  
  if values.Has("country_code") {
    tx = tx.Scopes(scopeB(strconv.Atoi(values.Get("country_code")))
  }
  
  if values.Has("age") {
    age, err := strconv.Atoi(values.Get("age")) 
    
    if err != nil {
      return tx, err
    }
    
    tx = tx.Scopes(scopeA(values.Get("country_code")))
  }
  return tx, nil
}
```